# How to install firefox in Amazon Cloud (AWS EC2)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firefox

I have an AWS account with all privileges. I wanted to install Firefox in the environment as my application will launch Firefox and run a few tests against the web application.

How do I install Firefox?

Comment: Depends on your operating system

Comment: My question is how to install firefox on Amazon cloud and how to get into the Amazon cloud to install ? I have choosen linux box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executing below commands solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb

sudo Xvfb :10 -ac

export DISPLAY=:10

sudo firefox
```

Comment: which version did you install?

Comment: This helped, but need to be more clear on the execution of this.  In one terminal, start the server on port :10 with 'Xvfb'.  In another terminal, export the Display port 10, and connect to that display port when firefox is launched.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Xvfb (X virtual framebuffer, virtual Linux display system) and Firefox.

For Ubuntu server:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb firefox
```

And then run your app via:

```
xvfb-run <your-app>
```

There are lot of tutorials how to run Firefox in headless mode. Just search for `headless firefox ubuntu`. One of good resource is: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless. In there, there are some options how to run your app under xvfb.

Comment: My question is how to install firefox on Amazon cloud and how to get into the Amazon cloud to install ?

Comment: Do you use EC2? If yes, just `ssh` to the instance and run the command in there.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample steps? What software i need to install for ssh in windows ?

Comment: You can use [Putty](http://www.putty.org/). See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html.