# Running Selenium on AWS Ubuntu - Error: Could not find firefox in your system PATH

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, ubuntu

I am running python 2.7.12 with selenium version 2.53.6 and firefox 46.0.1 on an AWS Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS instance. I've installed pyvirtualdisplay.

When I run this code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site- packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 55, in __init__
self.binary = firefox_binary or capabilities.get("binary", FirefoxBinary())
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 47, in __init__
self._start_cmd = self._get_firefox_start_cmd()
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 163, in _get_firefox_start_cmd
" Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox")
RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox
```

I've tried to add a link to my bash profile

```
echo export 'PATH="$PATH:/home/firefox"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

But have not been successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed firefox on the system (the application, not the driver)

Comment: Yes, I've installed it from here https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202131/firefox-started-by-selenium-ignores-the-display-created-by-pyvirtualdisplay

Comment: Try installing this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151809/how-to-install-firefox-in-amazon-clod-aws

Comment: I have xvfb installed already